Angular 15 - router.events are empty with nested router outlets on page refresh
I have the following structure:
App component with router outlet.
Layout component with router outlet (created in outlet of app component).
Customers component
App component -> router outlet -> Layout component -> router outlet -> Customers component
When the user navigates from orders to customers then router.events are not empty
it has the following events

NavigationStart
ChildActiationStart
ChildActivationEnd
NavigationEnd

But on Page refresh (/customers)
router.events are empty
this is working fine with angular 14.3.0 . It is not working since angular 15.0.0. This is only happening with router-outlet inside router-outlet.  I have a use case where i have to find subscribe to router events and look for router config path and outlet.
stackblitz url to replicate - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9kou58?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustomers%2Fcustomers.component.ts
